# Overloading operator() for a DiagonalMatrix object

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am writing a `DiagonalMatrix` class in C++ and I have trouble implementing the `operator()`:

```
double& DiagonalMatrix::operator() ( unsigned int i, unsigned int j )
{
  if( i == j and i < size() )
  {
    return mValues[i];
  } else
  {
    //What should I do here?
  }
}

const double& DiagonalMatrix::operator() ( unsigned int i, unsigned int j )
{
  if( i == j and i < size() )
  {
    return mValues[i];
  } else
  {
    //And here?
  }
}
```

`mValues` is an `std::vector< double >`.

What I want these operators to do is to return a reference to 0 if the 
element is not on the main diagonal and ignore the attempts to change such elements. How should I implement that?

Please feel free to suggest any other improvements to the code.

**EDIT**

Let me give you an example of the uses of `DiagonalMatrix`:

```
double a = myDiagMat(1,3);
//a must now be equal to 0;
myDiagMat(3,1) = 5;
//Ignores the assignment or gives an error
```

**More information**

I have these classes:

- `Matrix`

  - `BandedMatrix`
  - `DiagonalMatrix`
  - `DenseMatrix`
  - `BlockBandedMatrix`
  - `SparseMatrix`

I cannot show it here, but `DiagonalMatrix` is also a`BandedMatrix` (it is derived from it).

Every matrix has these two operators:

```
double& DiagonalMatrix::operator() ( unsigned int i, unsigned int j );
const double& DiagonalMatrix::operator() ( unsigned int i, unsigned int j ) const;
```

These operators are already implemented:

- Unary and binary `operator+` and `operator-`
- `operator+=` and `operator-=`
- `operator*` for various scenarios.

Comment: What behaviour do you want when someone does `myDiagonalMatrix(3,4) = 42.0;`?

Comment: As I said below, that won't work. I have the same problem with sparse matrices.

Comment: It is a rather bad idea to even consider "matrices" with individually mutable elements.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks, they were const references. I messed up while copying it here.

Answer (score 2):

With the updated question, the more typical approach would be to **not** return a reference. That makes the solution much more straightforward:

```
double DiagonalMatrix::operator() (unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const
{
    return (i == j) ? mValues[i] : 0;
}
```

Just don't support modifying individual elements of a matrix. If you want range-safety, you can instead use [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) which will be a little slower but throw `out_of_range` if `i` is too big:

```
double DiagonalMatrix::operator() (unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const
{
    return (i == j) ? mValues.at(i) : 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. We need those values to interact with other types of matrices, e.g., in matrix multiplication.

Comment: Um, no. A diagonal matrix **is-a** matrix.

Comment: @n.m. That wasn't actually listed as a requirement in the question, though regardless I provided a consistency answer as well.

Comment: @n.m. Alas, having a mutable `DiagonalMatrix` inherit from `Matrix` would be a violation of the LSP.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Mutable matrices are by themselves a violation of laws of nature, and probably some EU directive or two as well.

Comment: Won't not using references make it more expensive computationally?

Comment: @Furihr Why would it be more expensive? `double`s are cheap to copy.

Comment: @Barry It would be a rather confusing set of requirements then. If something is not a matrix, don't call it an <adjective> matrix.

Comment: @Barry, Copying it for millions of times would be less expensive than dereferencing?

Comment: @Furihr Did you time it?

Comment: @Barry, There is a problem with the solution you suggested. I have updated the question. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Furihr I didn't propose both a `const` and non-`const` operator. Either return a reference (and throw) or return a value (always, so don't need a non-`const` version).

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the specifications of your Matrix class. Assume things like sparse or diagonal matrices are not written yet so Matrix documentation cannot reference them.

If your specification includes correct assignments like `mat(i,j)=v` for arbitrary matrices, then your diagonal matrices **must** allow such things too, and behave correctly, and cease to be diagonal in the process. (Easy with the pimpl idiom, just replace the pimpl).

If it includes assignments like `mat(i,j)=v` for arbitrary matrices that can sometimes be ignored, or cause an exception, just always ignore them, or always cause an exception. This may sound like a waste of time, but it isn't. Interfaces and implementations mature to give more and more guarantees.

If it does not include such assignment, just don't implement it. You can still implement different assignment behaviour in different child classes.

It all boils down to a consistent specification. Have one (doesn't matter which one, any one will do) and you can implement it. Have a bad one, or none at all, and you are doomed. Ignoring an assignment when it makes no sense is a band-aid for a missing limb. (You can implement it, but you shouldn't, ever).

Comment: The first suggestion (a single argument operator(), or one that throws/asserts) makes no sense. A matrix must have **read** access to all its elements. The second suggestion is OK, as it provides read access to all elements (perfect) and no write access at all (also perfect; a matrix with mutable elements is a mathematical nonsense).

Comment: @n-m, What do you mean by "a matrix with mutable elements is a mathematical nonsense"? And, sorry to ask this, what does mutable mean exactly in this context?

Comment: Mutable means capable of change, here by means of assignment. A mathematical matrix doesn't change its elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a wrapper to allow your syntax, something like

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
    explicit Wrapper(double* ref) : ref(ref) {}

    Wrapper& operator = (double d) { if (ref) *ref = d; return *this; }
    operator double () { return ref ? *ref : 0.; }

private:
    double* ref;
};
```

And then

```
Wrapper DiagonalMatrix::operator() (unsigned int i, unsigned int j)
{
    return Wrapper{(i == j && i < size()) ? &mValues[i] : nullptr};
}

double DiagonalMatrix::operator() (unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const
{
    return (i == j && i < size()) ? mValues[i] : 0.;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/AbGOZS)